Push an item in deeply nested array if no exists (MongoDB with C# Driver)
I need help with this question. I have the following structure -
[
  {
    "Id": "a399f6c6-13b1-4060-8917-e99c54208165",
    "Watchlists": [
      {
        "Id": "0fddfa7a-528d-4fa9-9019-e2f7d7699427",
        "name": "MyWatchList",
        "Symbols": [
          {
            "SymbolName": "USD",
            "SymbolId": "0a61be6d-664f-4909-8743-83e202679abf"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "04280f42-0c02-4deb-9c47-4c255efb58d8",
        "name": "MyWatchList2",
        "Symbols": [
          {
            "SymbolName": "EURO",
            "SymbolId": "be2fe40c-e289-4ef6-b43e-28a6e72b296c"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

I need to add new symbols to the document (Watchlists.Symbols), and the symbols should not be repeated. That is, if there is already a symbol with a certain Id, then another symbol with the same Id (even if the SymbolName is different) should not be added to the list.
I wrote working code in mongoplayground - https://mongoplayground.net/p/v-udOKePMkQ
db.collection.update({
  "Id": "a399f6c6-13b1-4060-8917-e99c54208165"
},
{
  $push: {
    "Watchlists.$[element].Symbols": {
      "SymbolName": "USD",
      "SymbolId": "0a61be6d-664f-4909-8743-83e202679abf"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element.Id": "04280f42-0c02-4deb-9c47-4c255efb58d8",
      "element.Symbols": {
        "$not": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "SymbolName": "USD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  upsert: true
})

And I translated it into C# code -
   var baseFilter = Builders<UserWatchlistSetting>.Filter.Eq(x => x.UserId, userId);

   var update = Builders<UserWatchlistSetting>.Update
       .Push("Watchlists.$[d].Symbols", new Symbol { SymbolId = request.SymbolId, Name = request.SymbolName});

   var filter1 = new BsonDocument("d.Id", $"{request.watchlistId}");
   var filter2 = new BsonDocument("d.Symbols", new BsonDocument("$not", new BsonDocument("$elemMatch", new BsonDocument("SymbolId", $"{request.SymbolId}"))));

   var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
           {
               new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("$and",new BsonArray(){ filter1, filter2}))
           };

   return await mongoCollection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
   baseFilter,
   update,
   new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<UserWatchlistSetting> { IsUpsert = true, ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After, ArrayFilters = arrayFilters });

This code runs without errors, but the symbol is not added.I don't understand what the mistake in the code is.

Common steps to troubleshoot such questions:

Make sure that all filters you have actually works, you can check ids values or remove such filters and ensure that not filtered (all?) records updated. 2. Use update which returns the information about request in WriteResult https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#writeresult. Looking at it will provide you some details about taken steps. 3. Get generated actual query via steps mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78408929/9492730 and then compare it with your initial query


Can you share the full code for UserWatchlistSetting class including the classes for the nested properties?

I couldn't get filters to work with BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition, apparently there is an inconsistency in the parsing of identifiers. Instead of BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition, the JsonArrayFilterDefinition structure is now used.
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

var baseFilter = Builders<UserWatchlistSetting>.Filter.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);

var update = Builders<UserWatchlistSetting>.Update
    .Push("Watchlists.$[element].symbols", new Symbol { SymbolId = request.Symbols.First().SymbolId, Name = request.Symbols.First().SymbolName, Created = DateTime.UtcNow });

var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
{
  new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<Watchlist>("{'element._id': { $eq: UUID(\"" + watchlistId + "\")}, 'element.Symbols': {$not: {$elemMatch: {'_id': {$eq: UUID(\""+ request.Symbols.First().SymbolId +"\")}}}}}")
};

return await mongoCollection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
baseFilter,
update,
new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<UserWatchlistSetting> { IsUpsert = true, ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After, ArrayFilters = arrayFilters });

